# Exception on Startup with Neo4j 2.0 with Spring Data 3.0 Rest

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to upgrade to Neo4j 2.0, and Spring Data 3.0. I'm getting a null pointer when the application starts, before any of my code is executed.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error executing statement MATCH (ref:ReferenceNode {name:{name}}) RETURN ref; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error executing statement MATCH (ref:ReferenceNode {name:{name}}) RETURN ref; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query.CypherQueryEngine.query(CypherQueryEngine.java:56)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.ReferenceNodes.executeQuery(ReferenceNodes.java:77)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.ReferenceNodes.getReferenceNode(ReferenceNodes.java:81)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.SubReferenceNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.isStrategyAlreadyInUse(SubReferenceNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.java:95)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory.chooseStrategy(TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory.java:56)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory.<init>(TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory.java:39)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.typeRepresentationStrategyFactory(Neo4jConfiguration.java:146)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4b018b97.CGLIB$typeRepresentationStrategyFactory$6(<generated>)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4b018b97$$FastClassByCGLIB$$5306fd26.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:286)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4b018b97.typeRepresentationStrategyFactory(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
... 112 more
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error executing statement MATCH (ref:ReferenceNode {name:{name}}) RETURN ref; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query.CypherQueryEngine.parseAndExecuteQuery(CypherQueryEngine.java:67)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query.CypherQueryEngine.query(CypherQueryEngine.java:53)
... 128 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.prepare(ExecutionEngine.scala:75)
at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:60)
at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:65)
at org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.java:78)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query.CypherQueryEngine.parseAndExecuteQuery(CypherQueryEngine.java:65)
... 129 more
```

Neo4j and spring-data dependencies on Pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <springSecurity.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</springSecurity.version>
    <jackson.version>1.9.13</jackson.version>
    <neo4j.version>2.0.0</neo4j.version>
    <springDataNeo4j.version>3.0.0.RC1</springDataNeo4j.version>
    <neo4j-rest-graphdb.version>2.0.0</neo4j-rest-graphdb.version>
</properties>
<!--Neo4j-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>${springDataNeo4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-rest-graphdb</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j-rest-graphdb.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Context file

```
<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" />

<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestGraphDatabase">
    <constructor-arg value="http://localhost:7474/db/data"/>
</bean>

<context:annotation-config />
```

Neo4j is up and running.

When connecting through `http://localhost:7474/browser/` everything works fine, including the offending query MATCH (ref:ReferenceNode {name:{name}}) RETURN ref;

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you don't need any `org.neo4j.*` dependencies. Maybe it would work with only `<artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>` and `<artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rest</artifactId>`. This is the configuration you should try :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.RC1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rest</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.RC1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Update**

What is sure is that the error message is generated by `org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.ReferenceNodes` in `getReferenceNode` (http://bit.ly/1eDYlYS).

The `getReferenceNode` method is called only from one place in SDN, at `org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.SubReferenceNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy` (http://bit.ly/LW5gly).

This call is looking for a node with label `:ReferenceNode` and an attribute `name` equal to `root`.

So I would suggest trying to create such a node using Cypher :

```
CREATE (n:ReferenceNode {name:"root"}) RETURN n;
```

and see if the error still happens.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. You are right about not needing the org.neo4j.* dependencies. I excluded them and it build fine. However, I'm still getting the exactly same exceptions after the server starts.

Comment: I found this discussion that is perhaps related to your problem : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/XIHxfqJVWgc *"The reference node concept has been removed in Neo4j between version M06 and RC1. SDN 3.0 M1 still uses Neo4j 2.0 M06 and relies on the reference node. Thus, unfortunately, SDN can't yet be used with Neo4j 2.0 RC1."* but you're using 3.0.0.RC1 and not 3.0.0.M1 so you should check if it depends on a newer version of Neo4J.

Comment: According to this [commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/commit/8a440bdedf2961969bfc0a3f10f98077d1258191), which seems to be included in the 3.0.0.RC1, it is depending on Neo4j 2.0.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't solve. I think that the null pointer is being throw because of the parameters being passed to the query are null.

Comment: " parameters being passed to the query are null" - any news here?